# Cambio de huso horario

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

estoy haciendo pruebas para implementar Highcharts en una línea de producción. Los datos se envían cada pocos segundos a una Base de datos Mysql. El problema es que cuando cambie el huso horario para adoptar el de verano o invierno, el campo fecha se duplicará durante una hora. He probado insertando manualmente datetimes duplicados pero con diferente valor: se crea una doble línea pero los puntos para ver las etiquetas sólo aparecen en una de las líneas del gráfico. ¿Sabéis cómo solucionarlo? Gracias

Comment: Muestra el código que hayas probado para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y no la cierren.

Comment: Secundo. Muéstranos cómo estás haciendo esa prueba de insertar datetimes. También es importante ver cómo envías esos datos "cada pocos segundos" a la base MySQL. Es importante saber desde dónde vienen.

Comment: Me han entregado una tabla con los datos recogidos en  dos meses pasados. Mis pruebas no las hagoen tiempo real y la tabla no se actualiza dinámicamente. Realizo una conexión a Mysql desde mi Web de pruebas y el gráfico, estático,  se muestra en mi Web sin problema alguno. Todo es correcto, pero estoy pensando en el problema que surgirá cuando las tablas recojan los datos de los plc's en tiempo real y coincida el cambio de hora de verano a invierno o viceversa. He  descargado el código de un ejemplo de Highcharts y lo he adaptado a mis parámetros. La tabla tiene dos campos: Datetime y Valor.

Comment: Realmente el problema que anticipo y supongo que se producirá, será cuando a las 3AM, los relojes establezcan la hora a las 2AM. El tramo de 2AM a 3 AM se duplicará. y

Comment: marca cada ingreso con un hash codificado y unico en la base de datos, y en cada insert verifica que no se haya cargado anteriormente.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba creando un campo id clave y autoincrementable, pero en el eje x del gráfico, sólo aparece la fecha/ hora que coincide en los dos registros aunque tengan diferente id. En el eje y, muestra el valor (temperatura) diferente.